# How to split the name of each character into each row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

If the name has given each character of name should appear in each row

Name is like:

```
ABC
```

I want to be print output like:

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `chr(10)` method to introduce new line after each character.

Following function can achieve the same:

```
create or replace function string_to_individual_char(str varchar2) return varchar2 is
   cnt number := 0;
   str_to_return varchar2(1000) := '';
begin
   for cnt in 1..length(str) loop
      str_to_return := str_to_return||substr(str,cnt,1);
      if cnt != length(str) then
         str_to_return := str_to_return||chr(10);
      end if;      
   end loop;
   return str_to_return;
end;
/

show errors;
```

Sample usage:

```
set serveroutput on
SQL> select string_to_individual_char(ename) from scott.emp;

STRING_TO_INDIVIDUAL_CHAR(ENAME)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S
M
I
T
H

A
L
L
E
N
```